# Unable to get nokogiri xmlelement text value

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML content.

```
<info>
    <meta name="alias">alias1</meta>
    <meta name="score">.60</meta>
</info>
<info>
    <meta name="alias">alias2</meta>
    <meta name="score">.50</meta>
</info>
```

I need to get back for each value, but having difficulty doing so.

```
doc.xpath("//info").each do |info_entry|
  info_entry.xpath("meta").each do |meta_entry|
      if meta_entry['name'] == 'alias'
          the_alias = meta_entry.xpath('text()').text
      elsif meta_entry['name'] == 'score'
          score = meta_entry.xpath('text()').text
      end
      // add struct containing alias and score to list
  end
end
```

However, I'm not geting anything from text. I've tried many different things: inner_text, inner_html, content, value, nothing works. I've tried meta_entry.at, meta_entry.search, and so on.

Is there something I'm missing? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The xml you are showing is technically not valid, but I'm assuming you have some tags wrapping the whole thing, like `<xml>...your content...</xml>`.

Comment: it's surrounded by <html><body>...</html></body> and prefixed by: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of `xpath('text()')`. And you can get rid of the conditional and build a workable data structure as you go, like this:

```
def meta_contents(doc)
  doc.xpath("//info").map do |info_entry|
    info_entry.xpath("meta").map do |meta_entry|
      [meta_entry["name"], meta_entry.text]
    end.to_h
  end
end

>> meta_contents(doc)
#> [{"alias"=>"alias1", "score"=>".60"}, {"alias"=>"alias2", "score"=>".50"}]
```

Comment: Interesting. Your example worked. However, it doesn't work for me, when I pull the contents through Nokogiri::HTML(open("some_url")), and surrounded by html tags. i get the keys, but the values are blank.

Comment: Hi, I got it working. Changed to Nokogiri::XML, which did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ARay That's great. If this was helpful to you, please accept the answer as correct by clicking the grey checkmark next to my answer.